# Grails : MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))

Tags: mysql, grails

I am using Grails 2.3.4 and having trouble with named queries.
For example:

```
def c = Party.createCriteria()
        completedSearchList = c.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset){
            if(params.searchText) {
                or {
                    ilike("FirstName", "%${params.searchText}%")
                    ilike("pDate", "%${params.searchText}%")
                    "in"("user",users)
                }
                and {
                    eq("status","COMP")
                }
                and {
                    eq("projectID",session.projectID)
                }
            }
        }
```

Goal is to bring the search value written in the search field through param value and use Grails criteria to search.

But I am getting the error msg like:

```
Stacktrace follows:Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) and (this_.status='COMP') and (this_.projectid='bacrt') limit 10' at line 1
```

Comment: I'm not in grails but maybe you have to give addional keywords or commatas or so in your `or` part. I mean you combine every `and` but in your `or` you just write three lines with `like` and `in`. Thats looks a bit strange to me and maybe this causes the double paranthis which causes the syntaxerror. It looks like the `))` has something to do with your `in`-statement and the `or`statement that these are not correctly created. Hope this helps, but as said I'm not in grails.

Comment: on grails 2.3.0 I execute same query I dont see any error

Comment: try to log the sql statement. got to `datasource `and put `logSql=true`